# ExoPlayer Android дублирование(эхо) звука

Tags: android, аудио

Использую в своем приложение *ExoPlayer*. При повороте экрана, начинается накладываться звук от предыдущего видео, на текущее.

Все находится в фрагменте. Если просто пересоздавать(переключаюсь между видео таким образом) фрагмент, никаких проблем. Подозреваю, что аудио поток не гасится или уничтожение накладывается на создание фрагмента.

Видео  в приложении - *HLS*. Если сталкивались при работе с *ExoPlayer*'ом, подскажите что можно сделать в этой ситуации.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте добавить в манифест для тега вашего `Activity` такой атрибут:

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
```

Это предотвратит пересоздание `Activity`, а как следствие - и фрагментов при перевороте

Comment: Не помогло. Но подтолкнул меня к мысли - я прогнал логи, фрагмент создается два раза. Возможно в этом проблема.

Comment: @jangorussia, никто не знает в таком случае. Смотрите в свой код, у меня такой возможности нет